# Mysql Pagination

Tags: mysql, pagination

I am trying to understand how Pagination works in mySQL. Considering I have a lot of data that is to be retrieved based on select query how does adding different columns in the select statement change the pagination?

e.g.
`Select name from employee;`   vs `Select name, employeeId from employee`;

Will using employeeId in the select field help in retrieving data in more efficient manner even though that field in not required. Adding it as employeeId is indexed.

Thanks

Comment: Performance often depends on how much data you have, what `WHERE` conditions are present and what `ORDER` you want the results in. You haven't given any hints at to those here. If you could give a bit more detail in that regard it would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination deals with rows, not columns, and is as simple as a LIMIT clause:

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Would give you 10 rows starting from the 10th record.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit pagination in MySQL. If you are looking to implement pagination based on your query results, the LIMIT clause may come handy.

For example:

```
select name from employee limit a,b;
```

will return b rows from the table employee. These would be row numbers a+1 through a+b

```
select name from employee 0, 10
```

would return rows 1 through 10.

Using any number of columns will not affect the way you limit the number of rows which is normally referred to as pagination.